# faster way to get last element from string

Tags: php

I have a string similar to belows:

```
a_b_c_d_1
x_y_z_12
```

Now, you can see that last one is a number.
I want to extract it.

Steps that I used to follow were:

```
1. explode(string), and store in array
2. find length of array
3. get value at key (arrayLength)-1
```

But I think there must be fast and better way to do it. So, asking all you great guys here.

How can I achive following?

Comment: You can use $v = explode("_", $string); and then echo end($v); save you one step at least ;-)

Comment: What's slow about your method?

Comment: Also, do you want 2 or 12 for the second case?

Comment: I really liked solution from @PENDO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [strrpos](http://php.net/strrpos) to find the last occurrence of a string inside another string. You can skip the stuff with the if statement if you KNOW there's at least one occurrence of _, but here's a fail-safe approach:

```
$last_start = strrpos($string, '_');
if($last_start !== false) {
  $last_field = substr($string, $last_start);
}else{
  $last_field = $string;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
end(str_split($your_string))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :
`substr( strrchr($string,'_'),1);`